# Is it possible to convert a picture to a path in metapost? How?

Tags: metapost

Can I convert programatically a picture like the one below to a path in metapost?

```
picture myPicture;

myPicture := image(

fill
(294.660004,411.578003)--(307.644989,411.578003)--(307.644989,407.625000)           --(294.660004,407.625000)--cycle;

pickup pencircle scaled
1.285130bp;
draw (314.710999,409.601990)..controls (314.710999,402.113007) and
(308.640991,396.042999)..(301.152008,396.042999)            ..controls
(293.664001,396.042999) and
(287.593994,402.113007)..(287.593994,409.601990)            ..controls
(287.593994,417.089996) and
(293.664001,423.160004)..(301.152008,423.160004)            ..controls
(308.640991,423.160004) and
(314.710999,417.089996)..(314.710999,409.601990)            --cycle withcolor black

);
```

I'mk looking for something like:

```
path myPath;
myPath := pictureToPath(myPicture);
```

Comment: I don't think so, but you can iterate over the paths inside a picture: `for p within myPicture: ... endfor;` (but this could be a MetaFun extension, try it out)

Comment: You can do `draw bbox myPicture` but I guess that is not what you want.  But you can't get a full picture as a path.  In MP a `path` is a continuous path.  You can't have gaps. So in your example the circle and the bar would have to be separate paths.  @HenriMenke's suggestion is probably the closest you can do.

Comment: @HenriMenke `for p within picture` is plain MP (since at least 2010...)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about *why* you want the picture as a path?

Comment: @Thruston, I wanted to do some manipulations on the hole image and I thought I would need to convert the image to a path to be able to do it. See my answer to understand how I solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue - doing some manipulations on the hole image - without converting an image to a path: operating on *currentpicture*

Here is a simple example to show how I did it (my real use was a bit more complicated):

```
picture myPicture;

myPicture := image(

fill (294.660004,411.578003)--(307.644989,411.578003)--(307.644989,407.625000) --(294.660004,407.625000)--cycle;

pickup pencircle scaled 1.285130bp;

draw (314.710999,409.601990)..controls (314.710999,402.113007) and (308.640991,396.042999)..(301.152008,396.042999) ..controls (293.664001,396.042999) and (287.593994,402.113007)..(287.593994,409.601990) ..controls (287.593994,417.089996) and (293.664001,423.160004)..(301.152008,423.160004) ..controls (308.640991,423.160004) and (314.710999,417.089996)..(314.710999,409.601990) --cycle withcolor black

currentpicture := currentpicture shifted 100;

);
```